# Reactjs not rendering information correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a form where I can delete specific inputs using React. The problem is, react doesn't seem to be rendering the information correctly. This is my render function:

```
render: function(){
  var inputItems;
    if (this.state.inputs){
      inputItems = this.state.inputs.map(function(input){
      console.log(input)
      return (
        <Input
          input={input}
          onDestroy={this.destroy.bind(this, input)}
          onEdit={this.edit.bind(this, input)}
          editing={this.state.editing === input.id}
          onCancel={this.cancel} />
      );
    }, this);
  }

(...)
// this isn't the actual render return
return {inputItems}
```

and my destroy function:

```
destroy: function (input) {
  var newInputs = this.state.inputs.filter(function (candidate) {
    return candidate.id !== input.id;
  });

  this.setState({
    inputs: newInputs
  });
},
```

The actual destroy function is getting called through a child component via `<a href="#" onClick={this.props.onDestroy}>(Remove)</a>`. The interesting thing is that when I console log my inputs, as seen in the render function, the correct inputs are shown - the one I called the destroy function on is gone. But the incorrect inputs are rendered - it's always the very last one that disappears, not the one I called the destroy function on. So for example, I'll initially log:

```
First Name
Last Name
Email
```

and call the destroy function on the Last Name. The `console.log` will show:

```
First Name
Email
```

but the actual rendered information will show:

```
First Name
Last Name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Has to do with React child reconciliation. Added a `key={input.id}` to the `<Input>` tag and it works.

More information here under child reconciliation and dynamic children.
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Comment: Note that if you use controlled components (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) your form will always match your model data and you won't have this issue even if you forget to use keys.